# Will or be going to?

Tags: tense, will-vs-going-to

For the blanks in the following sentences, which tense is correct, will or be going to?

1. "Closed over the New Year period. This office _____ reopen on 2nd January." (A sign on an office window)
2. "The 2.35 to Bristol _____ leave from platform 5." (An announcement at a railway station)

Comment: In #1, I would just keep the present simple ".. this office reopens on... #2 depends heavily on the context.

Comment: Well I am required to choose between will and be going to

Comment: @Nogard: You shouldn't be required to make a choice between these two equally acceptable ways of expressing future tense. I suggest a more meaningful choice would be to opt for a different training course or teacher.

Comment: @fumblefingers: I appreciate your sarcasm but if the first one is a sign on an office door and the second one is an announcement at a railway station, what tense is normally used here?

Comment: Most people writing signs just want to get the message across, not write fine prose for others to admire. So my guess is they'd usually just write ***reopens / leaves*** in your examples. Almost nobody would bother writing out things like ***is going to reopen / leave*** in such contexts, but it wouldn't actually be *wrong*.

Comment: And how about will reopen/will leave?

Comment: @Nogard If you're restricted by those choices, choose "will" for the sign because it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

The form of the verb in both the situations depends on the context. However, these are my recommendations:

If it can be deduced from the context (if there is one) that the actions are certainly going to happen the way described in the sentence, you should use ***to be going to***. Anyways, I think you should choose this form for both of them, because there are certain details (the date and the place) specified in the body of the sentence:

1. This office **is going to reopen**...
2. The 2.35 to Bristol **is going to leave**...

In this context, both the forms are nearly equivalent, but the details are most likely the "decision-makers". However, both of them are equally acceptable.

---

However, if you would not be constrained to use these forms, and there is no context from which you can tell which one to use, I think you'd better off with:

1. This office *is reopening* on January 2nd. (present continuous - expresses plans)

When  it comes to the second sentence, I would use *is going to leave*, simply because travelling is (usually) carefully planned out and this form of the verb expresses a certain action.

### EDIT:

If the statements are written on signs, choose **will**, because it is shorter and matches such a context.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the first one is a sign placed on an office window and the second sentence is an announcement made at a railway station. In that case, what would be your opinion?

Comment: Still the same, but will is equally acceptable. It's unclear and they're nearly equivalent